# Ford TSB covered under warranty?

Tags: ford, transmission, shifting, warranty

I have a 2008 Mustang GT which seems to have the exact issue that is described by Ford TSB 09-09-06.

TSB can be viewed here :
http://www.stangpit.com/wp-content/images/docs/s197-tsb/09-09-06.pdf

Basically my transmission exhibits a harsh grind during the 2-3 shift if the transmission is cold. It will go away after about 5 minutes of driving (warms up) or if I shift very slowly from 2nd to 3rd. I have verified that I am clutching in all the way. My question is that I have a power-train warranty valid until December of 2013 from buying the vehicle as certified used through a Ford dealership. The TSB says that the service is eligible under new vehicle limited warranty coverage. What does that mean? Will this service be covered?

If the service is covered will it be worth doing? I honestly don't really trust dealerships that much to begin with. Could letting them rip apart and replace the synchros in my transmission just make things worse? I don't plan on driving the vehicle in cold weather too much anymore but I also don't want the situation to get worse overtime.

Answer (score 1):

TSB, or technical service bulletins, are most definitely covered under warranty by Ford *IF* your car experiences the problem.  This is the key difference between a recall and a TSB.

A recall is a mandatory item that MUST be taken care of by the dealer regardless if the problems exist.

A TSB is simply a bulletin informing the dealership that this may be the problem and this is how you fix it.  After warranty, TSB items are out of pocket.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work for BMW, so it might be different, but from my point of view YES. The warranty should cover the synchs, as they are not a "wear and tear" item like the brakes, clutch, etc. I can understand you trust issues, as I myself went back to school due to the perception we got as mechanics, but I wouldn't allow a problem to grow bigger because of it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it should, as long as you have the original warranty or one equivalent to it. Print out the TSB and bring it with you in case they try to tell you it's not covered. You might want to go through you warranty papers as well. Also, be sure to get a tech. to be in the car when you drive to show him the deal, emphasizing that it only does it when cold and that you are in fact using the clutch correctly.

Comment: Definitely take the TSB with you.  Without it, they'll just think you were beating on the car and wore out the synchros early.